# Label to display rating and border of the lable should be partially filled with color specific to rating ios

Tags: ios

```
self.rating.text=@"4.5";

self.rating.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;

self.rating.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

self.rating.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:8.0];

self.rating.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.2 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1].CGColor;

self.rating.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

self.rating.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

self.rating.clipsToBounds=YES;

self.rating.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
```

when i do this i get the following o/p

But i need the label border to be filled 90% assuming max rating will be five  and remaining red

Answer (score 0):

```
There are lots of ways to do it, but one is to just draw two bezier paths, one for each side:

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);

    UIBezierPath *blueHalf = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [blueHalf addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(100, 100) radius:90.0 startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:M_PI_2 clockwise:YES];
    [blueHalf setLineWidth:4.0];
    [blueHalf stroke];

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);

    UIBezierPath *redHalf = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [redHalf addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0) radius:90.0 startAngle:M_PI_2 endAngle:3.0 * M_PI_2 clockwise:YES];
    [redHalf setLineWidth:4.0];
    [redHalf stroke];
}
```

Comment: i have created a class that inherits from uilabel and then created an object of that label and then called setNeedsDisplay method but still it doesnot work                                                               Its not calling the drawrect method implemented in my label class

Comment: This way is not working the default corner radius was set to default black